# Single Finger Swipe Gesture only working with Pinch Gesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I'm trying to add a very simple swipe up gesture to one of my views. The gesture does not work at all unless I apply an outward/opposite pinch gesture with two of my fingers. I am creating the gesture connections via IB. I have set up the gesture properties to Swipe: Down and Touches: 1. However it will only work with a 2 finger outward pinching motion? What is going on? Thanks.

Edit:

Ok, I've tried coding it out rather than using interface builder and I'm getting the same results. Here is the code I'm using

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpOnVideoView = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeUp:)];
swipeUpOnVideoView.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
swipeUpOnVideoView.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.playerView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpOnVideoView];
```

As you can see I am specifically designating only 1 touch, however my SwipeUp: method will only execute if I use an outward pinching motion with two fingers???

Comment: Are you using a UISwipeGestureRecogniser?

Comment: Hi, yes. That's what's confusing to me. I am using the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, not the pinchGestureRecognizer as you would expect with my problem.

Comment: How about removing it from the Storyboard or Xib and adding it via code. Try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had a number of other `UITapGestureRecognizers` that were on my Xib file. Even though I wasn't calling them in the code anywhere they were associated with views on my page via the `connections inspector`. For some reason this interference made it so that my single finger swipeGesture would only register if I used a two finger pinching motion.

Deleting multiple `UITapGestureRecognizers` from my xib and then writing the code for the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` programmatically fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

check this it working proper in my application:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp:)];
[swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

- (IBAction)swipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // do you stuff here
}
```

May be it will help you.

Happy coding...:)

Comment: Hi Thanks, I'm not sure why this is happening, but I've copied and pasted your code into my application and it works... but still only if I use two fingers to swipe ???

Comment: It is working now, but this did not fix my problem. I've explained below what I had to do to fix it. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: welcome. to you...but i already given you uiswipegesture code ...anyway it's working for you then grate....if this helpful to you then accept or upvote my answer.